# JTDS (Java/MSSQL) - Could not find Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am using JTDS with Java to connect to a Microsoft SQL database.  I am able to connect to the database perfectly.  However when I run the code below, I am getting an error "Could not find stored procedure 'get_queue_items' ".  I've tried prefixing 'dbo.' to the stored procedure name, however I continue to get the error.  I've also included the actual stored procedure for reference.

```
try {
    // Prepare and call the stored procedure
    CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{call get_queue_items(?) }");

    // Register the ResultSet
    proc.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

    // Register Input Parameters
    proc.setInt("@last_queue_entry", 1);

    // Execute the stored procedure
    proc.execute();

    // If we have a ResultSet
    if (proc.getMoreResults()) {
        ResultSet rs = proc.getResultSet();
        if (rs.next()) {
            // to complete...
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

And the stored procedure:

```
USE [test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[get_queue_items]    Script Date: 11/17/2011 11:43:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_queue_items] @qid int OUT, @last_queue_entry int as
-- select all the new records out of the main table into a temp table
-- the temp table is what we will use to process

select @qid = qid from test.[dbo].que_items
where qid > @last_queue_entry
```

I'm new to JTDS and Java, so its likely I am at fault, but any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Changed the Stored Procedure as per Cristian's advice, still getting the same error 'Could not find stored procedure 'get_queue_items'

Edit 2: Still not working - database connectivity seems fine also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I met same problem and it seems to me that there is a bug in jTDS implementation. For me solution was procedure renaming and removing all underscore symbols (that is `getQueueItems(?)` in your case). Try, I think it must help to you.

Comment: Was this the fix? I'm getting the same error but removing underscore did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the output parameters, there are certain parameters that can not be specified as: text, ntext, and image.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[get_queue_items] @id int OUT, @last_queue_entry int as
-- select all the new records out of the main table into a temp table
-- the temp table is what we will use to process

select @id = id from test.[dbo].que_items
where qid > @last_queue_entry
```

this prodecure will return only id numbers

Comment: I modified the procedure exactly as above, and still getting the same error.

Comment: **connection** is connected to the DataBase [Test] ?

Comment: If I modify the line to this CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{call [test].[dbo].[get_queue_items](1) }");
 and remove the parameters is gives an error Error: Procedure or function 'get_queue_items' expects parameter '@last_queue_entry', which was not supplied.

Comment: So it knows the stored procedure, its just complaining how I am passing the variables in...

Comment: probe **proc.setInt("@last_queue_entry", 1);** with out the **@**

Comment: That's input parameters. Not output parameters.